# how to fix "cannot find -llib/cmocka.dll"

Tags: gcc, cmake

I'm trying to solve the problem, but nothing works. I don't understand why gcc looks for "-llib/cmocka.dll" when it should look for "cmocka.dll". Cmocka downloaded and showed the path to it. I tried to find a solution to the problem on the forums, but the same problem was described there on linux, and I have windows.I would appreciate any help as I don't know what to do anymore.
[image]

program structure:
[image]

root CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(tests LANGUAGES C ASM)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_subdirectory(src)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules")

# cmocka
find_package(CMocka CONFIG)
if (CMocka_FOUND)
    message("cmocka found")
    include(AddCMockaTest)
    include(AddMockedTest)
    add_subdirectory(test)
    enable_testing()
endif(CMocka_FOUND)
```

AddCMockaTest:

```
enable_testing()
include(CTest)

if (CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    if (WIN32)
        find_program(WINE_EXECUTABLE
                     NAMES wine)
        set(TARGET_SYSTEM_EMULATOR ${WINE_EXECUTABLE} CACHE INTERNAL "")
    endif()
endif()

function(ADD_CMOCKA_TEST _TARGET_NAME)

    set(one_value_arguments
    )

    set(multi_value_arguments
        SOURCES
        COMPILE_OPTIONS
        COMPILE_DEFINITION
        LINK_LIBRARIES
        LINK_OPTIONS
    )

    cmake_parse_arguments(_add_cmocka_test
        ""
        "${one_value_arguments}"
        "${multi_value_arguments}"
        ${ARGN}
    )

    if (NOT DEFINED _add_cmocka_test_SOURCES)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "No sources provided for target ${_TARGET_NAME}")
    endif()

    add_executable(${_TARGET_NAME} ${_add_cmocka_test_SOURCES})

    if (DEFINED _add_cmocka_test_COMPILE_OPTIONS)
        target_compile_options(${_TARGET_NAME}
            PRIVATE ${_add_cmocka_test_COMPILE_OPTIONS}
        )
    endif()

    if (DEFINED _add_cmocka_test_LINK_LIBRARIES)
        target_link_libraries(${_TARGET_NAME}
            PRIVATE ${_add_cmocka_test_LINK_LIBRARIES}
        )
    endif()

    if (DEFINED _add_cmocka_test_LINK_OPTIONS)
        set_target_properties(${_TARGET_NAME}
            PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS
            ${_add_cmocka_test_LINK_OPTIONS}
        )
    endif()

    add_test(${_TARGET_NAME}
        ${TARGET_SYSTEM_EMULATOR} ${_TARGET_NAME}
    )

endfunction (ADD_CMOCKA_TEST)
```

AddMockedTest:

```
function(add_mocked_test name)
  # parse arguments passed to the function
  set(options )
  set(oneValueArgs )
  set(multiValueArgs SOURCES MOCKS COMPILE_OPTIONS LINK_LIBRARIES LINK_OPTIONS)
  cmake_parse_arguments(ADD_MOCKED_TEST "${options}" "${oneValueArgs}"
    "${multiValueArgs}" ${ARGN} )

  # create link flags for mocks
  set(link_flags "")
  foreach (mock ${ADD_MOCKED_TEST_MOCKS})
    set(link_flags "${link_flags} -Wl,--wrap=${mock}")
  endforeach(mock)

  # define test
  add_cmocka_test(test_${name}
                  SOURCES test_${name}.c ${ADD_MOCKED_TEST_SOURCES}
                  COMPILE_OPTIONS ${DEFAULT_C_COMPILE_FLAGS}
                                  ${ADD_MOCKED_TEST_COMPILE_OPTIONS}
                  LINK_LIBRARIES ${CMOCKA_LIBRARIES}
                                 ${ADD_MOCKED_TEST_LINK_LIBRARIES}
                  LINK_OPTIONS ${link_flags} ${ADD_MOCKED_TEST_LINK_OPTIONS})

  # allow using includes from src/ directory
  target_include_directories(test_${name} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
endfunction(add_mocked_test)
```

Comment: Probably, it is your project who specifies the path incorrectly. Add your code to the question post. See also [ask].

Comment: What is content of `CMOCKA_LIBRARIES` variable? You may print it via `message(STATUS "CMOCKA_LIBRARIES: ${CMOCKA_LIBRARIES}")` command.

Comment: I get ```CMOCKA_LIBRARIES: lib/cmocka.dll```

Comment: Looks like you incorrectly set this variable (`CMOCKA_LIBRARIES`) and blame the compiler for using it (with `-l` option). The variable should contain **absolute path** to the `.lib` file. Originally, that variable is intended to be set by call [find_package(CMocka REQUIRED)](https://github.com/xbmc/libssh/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L74), which would use [FindCMocka.cmake](https://github.com/xbmc/libssh/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindCMocka.cmake) script shipped with your project. But in your code you transformed this call to `find_package(CMocka CONFIG)`.

Comment: There is a config file in cmocka 1.1.5: https://github.com/clibs/cmocka/blob/1.1.5/src/CMakeLists.txt#L54-L63. You should link to `cmocka::cmocka` import target.